# For every OS boot, a BIOS reset (apply defaults) is required to get Windows to boot. What is wrong?

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, bios, uefi

Recently, we installed an SSD on an HP ProOne 440 G3 which came with an HDD.

After the installation, we cloned the HDD on to the SSD.

Now, once we boot Windows, get work done, and shutdown, or restart for that matter, the BIOS fails to detect a bootloader on the SSD (it is not listed in the boot options as a bootable device).

Next, this is where it is driving me nuts.

We access the BIOS and simply choose the `Apply Defaults` option in the American Megatrends BIOS F.33.

Now when the system restarts after applying the defaults, the system works like nothing happened.

In a nutshell, for every shutdown or restart, we have to access the BIOS and apply the defaults in order for the system to boot from the SSD.

> Note: The boot mode is UEFI. So, is the SSD configured as.

What is the problem here?

Comment: Sounds like the battery (usually a CR2032) that stores firmware settings on your motherboard has gone flat.

Comment: @Mokubai If the battery isn't functioning then why are the rest of the firmware settings saved on the motherboard? I mean, if I enable virtualisation, save the setting, and exit the firmware, and then check to see if the setting was saved. It is not reset to disabled; it is being saved. Shouldn't that be forgotten too?

Comment: On modern UEFI systems most settings are stored in a non-volatile flash storage (NAND, like a USB memory stick) but can still use a coin-cell for RTC and other settings. It appears that your system may well have a lithium coin cell and it is entirely possible that they store the boot order settings in that same area... https://www.google.com/search?&q=HP+ProOne+440+G3+coin+cell otherwise it may be a firmware fault you may need to update your firmware...